# Is it possible to schedule a post with Linkedin Api

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to use linkedin API for sharing my web site post on linkedin. One of the feature is to schedule the post after some time or specific date. I would like to know is there any Api available for that where i can pass some parameter and the post is submitted on linkedin. 
Please help if anyone have done this before

Thanks!!

Comment: I don't think you can do it with the API, but you can definitely write a program that call the API to publish the post at the scheduled time

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes we can save the scheduling time the user select and write a program/cron job which picks the time and send to post Api.